# AWS Glue performance when write

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

After performing joins and aggregation i want the output to be in 1 file and partition based on some column.
when I use repartition(1) the time taken by job is **1 hr** and if I remove preparation(1) there will be multiple partitions of that file it takes **30 mins** (refer to example below).
So is there a way to write data into 1 file ??

```
...
...
df= df.repartition(1)
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = df,
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {
        "path": "s3://s3path"
        "partitionKeys": ["choice"]
        }, 
    format = "csv",  
    transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
```

Is there any other way to increase the write performance. does changing format helps? and how to achieve parallelism by having 1 file output

S3 storage example

```
**if repartition(1)** // what I want but takes more time
choice=0/part-00-001
..
..
choice=500/part-00-001

**if removed** // takes less time but multiple files are present
choice=0/part-00-001
 ....
 choice=0/part-00-0032
..
..
choice=500/part-00-001
 ....
 choice=500/part-00-0032
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using df.repartition(1)

USE df.repartition("choice")

```
df= df.repartition("choice")
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = df,
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {
        "path": "s3://s3path"
        "partitionKeys": ["choice"]
        }, 
    format = "csv",  
    transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The repartition method of the DynamicFrame class does not accept a parameter of type string ... only integer. To make this work you would need to convert df into a Spark DataFrame. The repartition method here actually does what you want. Then you can convert it back into an DynamicFrame and use the DynamicFrameWriter ...

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have one single file, use coalesce instead of repartition, it avoids data shuffle.

Comment: Tried using coalesce similar time was consumed